# Ionic Android 4.3 Backspace Input not working

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have a weird problem with the backspace key on Android and Ionic.

I'm trying to implement a simple input for 4 character groups (max length = 3).
I've written a directive in order to automatically format the input accordinly, and foucs the next input once the max length is reached. This works fine on iOS and Android 5+.

However if I run this code on a Samsung S3 (4.3) sometimes the backspace key is not working. That is -> Input has focus, however the value does not get deleted. Adding another character is working fine.

Here is the code:

```
.directive('autoNext', function($timeout) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attr, form) {

    var tabindex = parseInt(attr.tabindex);
    var maxLength = parseInt(attr.ngMaxlength);


     element.bind("input propertychange", function (e) {

       element.val(element.val().toUpperCase());
       element.val(element.val().replace(/-/g, ''));
       if (element.val().length > maxLength - 1) {
         var original = element.val();
         var remaining = original.substring(maxLength, original.length);
         var newvalue = original.substring(0, maxLength);
         element.val(newvalue);
         element.triggerHandler('change');
         var newIndex = tabindex + 1;
         var tag = '[tabindex="' + newIndex + '"]';
         var next = angular.element(document.querySelector(tag));
         if (next.length > 0) {
           var nextElement = angular.element(next[0]);

           // if(!(ionic.Platform.isAndroid() && ionic.Platform.version() <= 4.3)) {
             if (remaining.length > 0) {
               nextElement.val(remaining);

               if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
                 next[0].focus();
               } else {
                 $timeout(function () {
                   next[0].focus();
                 }, 5);
               }
               return nextElement.triggerHandler('propertychange');
             } else {
               return false;
             }
           // }
         }
         else {
           return false;
         }
       }
       return true;
     });
```